# How do I manage my data when creating a calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, calendar

I am developing an iOS calendar app using swift.
I'm using a firebase database because the server needs some data.
But it takes too long to fetch data, and nothing is visible unless there's a wifi (or cellular) connection.
I want to make my schedule visible even if I turn off wifi or cellular, like Google Calendar or iCalendar.
I heard that there are sqlite, realm, and core data available. Which of these should you use? Can all three be synchronized with firebase?

Comment: You should use whatever database fits with your business model needs. There are [many blog post](https://rollout.io/blog/ios-databases-sqllite-core-data-realm/) covering the differences between this databases but yes, the approach here should be fetching data from your local db and updating it from firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firebase then there is no need of using another Database or saving mechanism. Firebase has offline Capabilities which should suffices your situation. 
Have a look at this [Offline-Capability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

You can enable offline access with just single line of code:

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

With this enabled, Firebase will automatically handle the synchronisation.

Comment: I think It is not for showing data offline but it performs queue operations like when you are sending any event during offline state and come back to online then perform that event. `To show user's data offline you can use Realm`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, it does save the data locally so that you can use it when the device is offline. I've implemented this in one of my projects for Chat

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is one more problem, slow loading speed. Can firebase improve the time it takes for data to appear when the app starts?

Comment: When you enabled the offline capability. The speed will be up as it will show the content from local copy till it's being loaded from the network. Give it a try